# T-SQL exec master..xp_cmdshell sqlcmd command unable to include variable output path

Tags: sql-server, variables, sqlcmd, bcp, xp-cmdshell

I am trying to generate the output result to a `.txt` file dynamically with whatever the value of @name will be, it will be generated automatically via cursor, just to show an example, I've showed as SET.

Below is the code I am trying to exec, it says incorrect syntax at +

```
declare @name nvarchar(max); SET @name = 'test1'
exec master..xp_cmdshell 'sqlcmd -s, -W -Q "set nocount on; select * from [EDI].[dbo].[Vendor]" | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > '\\shared data\Everyone\'+@name+'+'.txt'"'
```

If I just enter the entire path without any variables, the code works perfectly fine.

I have tried `bcp` too, but its skipping the column headers. So, I've tried to do the union all thing but it throws error saying incorrect column name. Hence trying to use `sqlcmd`. Please help me out.

Thank you

Comment: Try saving to a variable and pass that instead.

Comment: yeah ive saved to @name and ive been passing it right, also ive tried the entirety too

`@name` = '\\shared data\Everyone\'+`@name`+'+'.txt'"' and exec as

 | findstr /v /c:"-" /b > `@name'`

still doesnt work

Comment: Execute clause doesnt allow complex expressions in parameters. Create full string before the execute and put the value into a variable which you pass as parameter

Comment: Also beware of datatype of the string. Usually these extended procedures doesn't like nvarchar(max)

Comment: It's not a limitation of `xp_cmdshell` (which you probably shouldn't be using anyway, btw), it's a syntax limitation of stored procedure calling generally. When supplying stored procedure parameters they must be either a literal or a scalar variable, you cannot use an expression in-situ. So concatenate the components of your command into a scalar variable and then `exec master..xp_cmdshell @command`.

Comment: What an odd thing to do. Why call out to cmd only to call back in to SQL Server?